# What is the difference?

Tags: league-of-legends

What's the meaning of these phrases in League of Legends? Does it all mean "Lots of kills", or is there any difference between them?

`Killing spree` `Rampage` `Legendary` `Godlike` `_____kill`

[EDIT]How short is "short time"?; Is there any logo for Hexakill+?; Are Hexakill onwards removed in a patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Ultrakill" doesn't exist in League of legends.

There are titles for killing multiple enemies within a short time:

```
Doublekill - Kill 2 enemies
Triplekill - Kill 3 enemies
Quadrakill - Kill 4 enemies
Pentakill  - Kill 5 enemies
Hexakill   - Kill 6 enemies
```

There also was the "Legendary Kill" which required you to kill 6 enemies in a 5v5 game, however this has been removed since it was almost impossible.

Apart from the Double to Hexakill streaks, there are also titles for killing sprees that require you to kill a certain amount of enemies without dying.

```
Killing Spree - Kill 3 enemies without dying
Rampage       - Kill 4 enemies without dying
Unstoppable   - Kill 5 enemies without dying
Dominating    - Kill 6 enemies without dying
Godlike       - Kill 7 enemies without dying
Legendary     - Kill 8 + enemies without dying
Shutdown      - Kill an enemy on a killing spree
```

The killstreaks above will **not** be interrupted by being executed (a monster or turret kills you  without any help of a player)

Comment: So what's the difference between Legendary Kill and Hexakill?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 It's basically the same. It was reintroduced and renamed with the introduction of the Hexakill Gamemode.

Comment: One more question, how short is the "short time"? How is it counted?

Comment: Another one xD I hope it's not off topic: Is there any logo for Hexakill+? (like the pentakill logo here: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HeA2v7ghn_0/VCcmhxJV_WI/AAAAAAAAAjE/jMVMBFWeeo0/s1600/League%2Bof%2BLegends%2B2014-09-27%2B16-03-24-06.jpg)

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 Whenever you kill several champions within 10 seconds of each other. You get 30 seconds after a quadra kill if no enemies respawn. (Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill#Multi_Kill)

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 Yes there is a logo. (http://i.imgur.com/mQhjphD.jpg)